# SPF neutral on mail sent with SMTP from Gmail. SPF pass on mail sent from inbox for that address on G Suite

Tags: email, spf, g-suite

The domain name I'm trying to debug is dallaspetsalive.org. This is a G Suite domain.

When I log directly into my G Suite email account for the dallaspetsalive.org address and send an email, I get SPF pass result:

`Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of someaccount@dallaspetsalive.org designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.41;`

When I log into my personal gmail account and send email as the dallaspetsalive.org address using SMTP I've set up in the settings, I get SPF neutral result:

`Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 209.85.220.41 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of someaccount@dallaspetsalive.org) client-ip=209.85.220.41;`

Does using SMTP in another inbox to send email ruin SPF? It appears to be checking the same IP, but giving a pass result in one case and a neutral case in the other, and I can't make any sense of it.

This is what I have for the TXT record for SPF. The non-Google addresses are services we use:

`v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:_spf.neonemails.com include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am trying to optimize our email settings to avoid mail going to spam.

Comment: I can't make any sense of it either. The sending IP address is the only thing that SPF cares about. The only idea I have is that this result could happen if you did that test within an hour of adding `_spf.google.com` to your TXT record and the second receiving server had the old record without it cached. Does it still happen if do the same test now?